# What this error means in Opencv Java?

Tags: java, sockets, opencv, image-processing

I am working on Streaming Webcam Video on multiple client through java Socket
When two or More Client are connected then this error occurs.
Plz Help on This error cant understand the cause.

```
OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -10 (Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported)) in cv::BaseImageEncoder::throwOnEror, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\grfmt_base.cpp, line 131
OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -10 (Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported)) in cv::BaseImageEncoder::throwOnEror, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\grfmt_base.cpp, line 131 
OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -10 (Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported)) in cv::BaseImageEncoder::throwOnEror, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\grfmt_base.cpp, line 131Exception in thread "Thread-12" Exception in thread "Thread-5" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\grfmt_base.cpp:131: error: (-10) Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported) in function cv::BaseImageEncoder::throwOnEror
]
at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imencode_1(Native Method) 
at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imencode(Imgcodecs.java:487)
at Server.VirtualClassRoomServer$WebCamClientThread.run(VirtualClassRoomServer.java:363)
CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\grfmt_base.cpp:131: error: (-10) Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported) in function cv::BaseImageEncoder::throwOnEror]
at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imencode_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imencode(Imgcodecs.java:487
at Server.VirtualClassRoomServer$WebCamClientThread.run(VirtualClassRoomServer.java:363)
OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -10 (Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported)) in cv::BaseImageEncoder::throwOnEror, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\grfmt_base.cpp, line 131
Exception in thread "Thread-10" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\grfmt_base.cpp:131: error: (-10) Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported) in function cv::BaseImageEncoder::throwOnEror
]
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imencode(Imgcodecs.java:487)
    at Server.VirtualClassRoomServer$WebCamClientThread.run(VirtualClassRoomServer.java:363)
```

This is the server side code

```
class WebCamServerThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            WebCamServer=new ServerSocket(WebCamPort);
            while (true) {                    
                WebCamSocket=WebCamServer.accept();
                WebCamClientThread StartWebCamClientThread=new WebCamClientThread(WebCamSocket);
                StartWebCamClientThread.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VirtualClassRoomServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}



class WebCamClientThread extends Thread{
     Socket NewSocket;
    public WebCamClientThread(Socket NewSocket) {
        this.NewSocket=NewSocket;
        WebCam=new VideoCapture(0); 
    }



     @Override
    public void run() {

       ObjectOutputStream SendMessage = null;
         try {
             SendMessage = new ObjectOutputStream(NewSocket.getOutputStream());
             while(true){
                 if(WebCam.grab()){
                     try {

                         WebCam.retrieve(Frame);
                         Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", Frame, mem);//This line has the error
                         Image Video=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray()));
                         BufferedImage SendVideo=(BufferedImage) Video;
                         ImageIcon img=new ImageIcon(SendVideo);

                         SendMessage.writeObject(img);
                         SendMessage.reset();
                     } catch (IOException ex) {
                         Logger.getLogger(VirtualClassRoomServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                     }
                 }
             }} catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(VirtualClassRoomServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         } finally {
             try {
                 SendMessage.close();
             } catch (IOException ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(VirtualClassRoomServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

This is the Client side code:

```
class WebCamClientThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            Socket WebCamSocket=new Socket(GetIp,1013);
            VideoStream=new ObjectInputStream(WebCamSocket.getInputStream());
            WebCamClientStreamThread getStream=new WebCamClientStreamThread();
            getStream.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VirtualClassRoomClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}

class WebCamClientStreamThread extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {        
            try {
                int x=0,y=0;
                ImageIcon imageIcon = (ImageIcon) VideoStream.readObject();                 
                Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
                image = image.getScaledInstance(jPanel2.getWidth(),jPanel2.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_FAST);
                Graphics DrawImage=jPanel2.getGraphics();
                DrawImage.drawImage(image, 0, 0, jPanel2.getWidth(), jPanel2.getHeight(), null);
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(VirtualClassRoomClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which opencv version do you have? And are you on OSX?

Comment: Opencv 3.0 and I am on windows 10

Comment: Should I post code for your understanding

Comment: @HemantSangle That would be helpful.

Comment: And also check if you have valid network connection. From the log it looks like the sockets are having problem with data transfer.

Comment: @marol I have posted the sending and receiving code and commented the line where the exception is thrown and also this Works fine on the network when only one client is connected

Comment: @marol check the code plz...